# Finite population correction factor and bootstrapped-quantile confidence intervals

Tags: bootstrap, survey, finite-population

I'm calculating the confidence intervals around an estimate using bootstrapping techniques.  I'm particularly fond of the percentile method, given its simplicity and general intuitive nature.  However, I'm also interested in applying the finite population correction factor ($fpc$) to adjust the lower and upper bounds of the confidence interval to reflect certain situations in which the total population has been sampled extensively (i.e. $n/N \geq 0.10)$.  Since the confidence interval is no longer a function of the $\hat{se}$ and the $fpc$ is applied to the $\hat{se}$, I'm not sure how to incorporate the $fpc$ into the construction of the confidence intervals.  One idea would be to adjust the $\alpha$th percentile of the bootstrapped distribution to use (i.e. $\hat{\theta}^{*(\alpha)}$), so as to reflect the $fpc$ in a simlilar fashion to how $BC_{a}$ confidence intervals are constructed.  So instead of grabbing the 2.5% and 97.5% quantiles, I might obtain some sort of $fpc$ corrected quantiles.  Just wanted to make sure this method was theoretically sound and also how I might actually go about doing it.

Comment: This paper is a good survey of techniques for dealing with finite populations. Most of the techniques discussed involve adjusting the bootstrapping methodology itself rather than applying a factor after the fact: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ssu/1458047831